# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Here is the column in entity,

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SLLNO_GENERATOR", sequenceName = Config.DB_SCHEMA_MERCH_PAY+".MERCHANT_PAY_DETAILS_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SLLNO_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="SLNO")
    private Long slno; //NUMBER
```

in database this column has the NOTNULL constraint.
but this is not the primary key.

This sequence is in the database. all the permissions are granted.

in runtime, I need to insert data into this table.
since the value of this column is generated by a sequence, it gives below error,

```
Mar 26, 2024 7:00:38 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
Mar 26, 2024 7:00:38 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MMONEY_MERCHPAY"."MERCHANT_PAY_DETAILS"."SLNO")

Mar 26, 2024 7:00:38 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]
```

Anyone knows what is the reason for this issue...